# WPF multithread with events

Tags: c#, events

I read lines from file and each line show in textbox. I use event but app stop and wait load all lines. After show all line. Here is code:
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            reader.OnReadLine += Message;
        }

```
    private void Message(object sender, LineEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        textBox.Text += e.Content + "\n";
                        textBox.Focus();
                        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;

                    }));
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
        var x = taskFactory.StartNew(() => reader.Read());
        Task.WaitAll(x);
    }
}
class LineEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Content { get; }

    public LineEventArgs(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }
}


delegate void OnReadLineHandler(object sender, LineEventArgs e);
class FileReader
{
    public event OnReadLineHandler OnReadLine;

    public void Read()
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                OnRead(streamReader.ReadLine());      
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnRead(string text)
    {
        if (OnReadLine != null)
            OnReadLine(this, new LineEventArgs(text));
    }
}
```

Thanks for advice

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(x);` will block the current `Dispatcher` so, your `TextBox` isn't updated until all lines are readed. Stange that it won't Lock up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the UI to wait for the entire file to be read because you're saying `Task.WaitAll(x)` Meaning, you saying, "Wait till this is done." Instead use await like below.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
    var x = taskFactory.StartNew(() => reader.Read());
    await x;
}
```

Notice I also maid the method async by changing: `private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` to `private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Give that a try and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I have small problem. Lines are displayed sequentially, but window gets stuck and can not click on anything until it has finished loading.

Comment: I dont know. I changed only button_Click method to async.